# How to implement viewpager with stackview type look and feel

Tags: android-viewpager, stackview

I need to implement viewpager that has look & feel and animation as that of stackview widget in android. I have already looked into 
https://github.com/blipinsk/FlippableStackView/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/bartoszlipinski/flippablestackview.
But this doesn't fit my purpose, as the views are animated via flip animations.Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solved the problem by implementing custom PageTransfrormer.

code:

public class DepthPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

```
private static final float DEFAULT_CURRENT_PAGE_SCALE = 0.8f;
private int dimen;

public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    view.setScaleX(DEFAULT_CURRENT_PAGE_SCALE);
    view.setScaleY(DEFAULT_CURRENT_PAGE_SCALE);
    dimen = view.getWidth();

    if(position < -1) {
        view.setAlpha(0);

    } else if(position <= 0) {
        view.setAlpha(1.0f);
        view.setTranslationX(0);
        view.setTranslationY(0);

    } else if(position <= 1+1) {
        view.setTranslationX(dimen * -position);
        view.setAlpha(-0.5f * position + 1.0f);
        view.setTranslationX((-dimen / 1.1F) * position);
        view.setTranslationY((dimen / 9.9f)*position);

    } else {
        view.setAlpha(0);
    }

}
```

}

usage:
instantiate viewpager and then set custom viewpager transformer as:-
viewpager.setPageTransformer(true,new DepthPageTransformer());